# How to apply javascript to every element?

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

I am having a profile card and it has some hovering effect using js but when I copy paste the code to create 2 profile cards, the js is only applied to one card. What should I do.
Code:

```
    <script>
        const clc = document.querySelector(".cancel").
        const arr = document.querySelector(".arr_container");
        const left_container = document.querySelector(".left_container");

        arr.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            arr.classList.add("active_arr");
            if(left_container.classList.contains("off")){
                left_container.classList.remove("off");
                left_container.classList.add("active");
            }
        });
        clc.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            arr.classList.remove("active_arr");
            if(left_container.classList.contains("active")){
                left_container.classList.remove("active");
                left_container.classList.add("off");
            }
        });
        
    </script>
```

I tried using onclick function.`your text`

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: You probably need to combine `querySelectorAll` and `forEach` to `addEventListener` to every card element.

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector` return a single element of the content, so you need to use `querySelectorAll` instead. `querySelectorAll` returns an array of elements, so you will loop over the array to add your `EventListener`

```js
const arr = document.querySelectorAll(".arr_container");

arr.forEach((card) => {
  card.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
      arr.classList.add("active_arr");
      if(left_container.classList.contains("off")){
          left_container.classList.remove("off");
          left_container.classList.add("active");
      }
  });
});
```